# Regex URL rewrite - Variables $1 and $2 from two (.*) sets

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

Looking for help in working out what I'm doing wrong in regex. Want to take a URL with two variables and apply in different format in new URL.

E.g.

```
FROM /resources/author/john+smith
TO /resources/tag/john-smith
```

Here's my regex:

```
FROM /resources/author/(.*)+(.*)
TO /resources/tag/$1-$2/
```

The above isn't working. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's helpful for anyone else in the future, I managed to fix it myself - see below for answer:

Made the regex as follows:

```
FROM /resources/author/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)[+]([A-Za-z0-9-]*)
TO /resources/tag/$1-$2/
```